# How to create a custom pom dependecy which contains multiple jars? Is it possible?

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, repository, customization

My project contains around 30 jars which does not have a maven dependency settings.
So I  have to manually add the jars in th local maven repo and then use the custom maven dependencies to project.
However I have to add 30 dependencies in the POM file which I feel might not be a good way to do it.
Is there any way so that those all 30 jar files can be added with a single pom dependency?

For adding the jar in the local maven repo and then use the dependency, I am using below method:

Ex:

```
$ mvn install:install-file -Dfile=c:\kaptcha-{version}.jar -DgroupId=com.google.code 
    -DartifactId=kaptcha -Dversion={version} -Dpackaging=jar
```

and then use the dpendency as below:

```
 <dependency>
          <groupId>com.google.code</groupId>
          <artifactId>kaptcha</artifactId>
          <version>2.3</version>
 </dependency>
```

Kapcha jar is just for reference and I have dfferent 30 jars to add in repo and use in the project.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I would check whether you can draw a fair amount of these dependencies form MavenCentral (avoiding the manual hassle).

Secondly, if you are in a company with more than two Java developers, you should set up a Nexus or Artifactory server to handle the JARs. So no manual installation any more.

After saying this: You can create a POM that contains a list of dependencies. If you add this POM as dependency in your project, then all the dependencies of the POM will become (transitive) dependencies of your project.

Comment: I already added available jars through maven but after that also around 30 jars are proprietary and not available in maven.

Comment: Do you mean, I must have to add rest 30 dependencies in the pom file? Please elaborate your third point

Comment: The dependencies must be declared _somewhere_ . Either in your own POM, or a POM you use as dependency. So if you have 30 jars, you need thirty `<dependency>` entries.

Comment: My question is whether we can have a single dependency with all jars?

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure what you are asking me. I said that you can define an additional POM that lists all the thirty dependencies and then you can use this POM as dependency in your projects. You cannot just add several JARs at once in one `<dependency>` entry.